# csv files in opencpu

Tags: r, csv, opencpu

If I put a very small csv file in my GitHub directory so that it gets copied to /ocpu/github/username/projectname/www/ , will I be able to access the contents of the csv for use in a R function? I tried to ajax the file, but I get a 404 error even though I can see the csv file sitting in the www directory of my local server. I need to have the csv on the server as a static file rather than being uploaded by a function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access them like any other file. Can you post an example that shows what you are doing and what error you are getting?

That said, if you just want to use this data in your R functions, it is better to include it in the R package as an actual data file. Also see section 1.1.6 of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages). An example is the [mapapp](https://github.com/opencpu/mapapp) package, which includes a dataset called [countryExData](https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/mapapp/R/countryExData/csv). Also see the [live app](https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/mapapp/www/).